# How to add greek polytonic with setxkbmap

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, lxde

I want to add greek polytonic keyboard layout under Lubuntu (so in LXDE). I already realized there is no easy tool to do it with the graphic interface, so I need to use `setxkbmap` executing something the like of:

```
setxkbmap pl,gr
```

Now, how to make `setxkbmap` set the greek polytonic variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set it with `setxkbmap`:

```
setxkbmap 'pl,gr' -variant ',polytonic' -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'
```

`-variant` sets variants for each selected layout and `-option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'` enables switching layouts with Alt-Shift.

The available layouts and variants can be seen in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. Every layout has its file and by listing such file you can find the variants of the layout.

(BTW the options are listed in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.)

If you need to make the settings permanent, instead of using `setxkbmap`, you can edit `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the setxkbmap to autostart with the polytonic variant like this

```
echo '@setxkbmap -layout "us,gr,gr" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle" -variant ",,polytonic"' | sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

This is a combination of Alt+Shift keys to change the layout and for En(us)-Gr languages switch.

Done.